# Installin RabbitMQ server from command line

Tags: cmd, rabbitmq, silent

How to install RabbitMQ server https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html from command line in silent mode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've done this before by just downloading the zipped version then extracting it and running the relevant commands:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.5.4/rabbitmq-server-windows-3.5.4.zip -OutFile C:\downloads\rabbitmq.zip

7z x C:\downloads\rabbitmq.zip -oC:\rabbitmq -aoa

# run RabbitMQ
Start-Process -FilePath C:\rabbitmq\rabbitmq_server-3.5.4\sbin\rabbitmq-server.bat
```

If you want it installed as a service you can use the `rabbitmq-service.bat` script - https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-service.8.html

```
rabbitmq-service install
```